# Play framework app heroku configuration error: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'application.prod.conf'

Tags: heroku, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0

I built an app based on template play-silhouette-seed-slick. [template link](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-silhouette-seed-slick)

I got a configuration error caused by com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse after deploying the app to heroku.

> "Configuration error: Configuration error[ @ file:/app/target/universal/stage/conf/: 2: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'application.prod.conf' (if you intended 'application.prod.conf' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)]"

The Procfile

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/panobike-plus-server -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.resource=${PLAY_CONF_FILE}
```

And app.json

```
{
    "name": "play-silhouette-slick-seed",
    "description": "Seed project to show how Silhouette can be implemented into a Play Framework application with database access using Slick 3.",
    "keywords": [
      "Play",
      "Silhouette",
      "Slick"
    ],
    "website": "https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed",
    "repository": "https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed",
    "success_url": "/",
    "env": {
      "BUILDPACK_URL": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git",
      "PLAY_CONF_FILE": "application.prod.conf",
      "PLAY_APP_SECRET": "changeme",
      "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID": "",
      "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
      "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID": "",
      "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
      "TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY": "",
      "TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET": ""
    }
}
```

In my production config "application.prod.conf", there is no such key "application.conf".
What does this error message mean?

Thank you

Comment: Your app.json has a syntax error - there is no closing curly bracket for the key "env". Is this on purpose?

Comment: That was a typo, I do have a closing curly bracket for "env", I did not change this file since I pull it from github. @Anton

Answer (score 1):

It was a stupid question.
I did not call the https://api.heroku.com/app-setups endpoint to setup the app.json enabled application on Heroku.

Comment: I have the same issue, what's the app-setups endpoint? can you improve your answer to be more detailed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use heroku since 2017. I cannot remember what app-setups uses for...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. That was due to lack of `PLAY_CONF_FILE` env variable. To fix this error you need to open Heroku web page -> Settings -> click on `Config Vars` button and set new PLAY_CONF_FILE variable. For example application.staging.conf